# Scala: "required: scala.concurrent.Future[?]"

Tags: scala

### Edit

Still haven't found a solution so I ended up creating two `someFuture` methods. One that returns a future & one that doesn't (to get `otherFuture` to compile)

---

I'm trying to return `Future[Option[JsObject]]` but keep getting this error:

```
required: scala.concurrent.Future[?]
```

What I'm doing

```
def someFuture:Future[Option[JsObject]] =
  Future {
    Option(JsObject())
  }

def otherFuture:Future[Option[JsObject]] =
  Future {
    Option(JsObject(
      someFuture.flatMap(_.get)
    ))
  }

// get error here
found   : JsObject
[error]  required: scala.concurrent.Future[?]
```

How can I return the JsObject without getting an error?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `someFuture.flatMap(_.get)` won't compile—you need to provide a function that takes a `JsObject` and returns a `Future[Whatever]` to use `flatMap` on `someFuture`.

You probably want something like this:

```
def otherFuture: Future[Option[JsObject]] = someFuture.map { opt =>
  Option(JsObject(opt.get))
}
```

There's not really any reason to use `Option` if you're just going to call `.get` on it like this, though, so the following might be better:

```
def otherFuture: Future[Option[JsObject]] = someFuture.map(_.map(JsObject(_)))
```

Now if the future is satisfied by a non-empty option, the contents of the option will be wrapped in another layer of `JsObject`, which seems to be what you're aiming for?

Note that if you're using `Option` to represent failure, you may want to consider the failure-handling that's built into `Future` instead.

Comment: Getting a different error this time at "JsObject": `overloaded method value apply with alternatives:
[error]   (fields: Map[String,spray.json.JsValue])spray.json.JsObject <and>
[error]   (members: List[(String, spray.json.JsValue)])spray.json.JsObject <and>
[error]   (members: (String, spray.json.JsValue)*)spray.json.JsObject
[error]  cannot be applied to (spray.json.JsValue)
`

Comment: I was just following your use of `JsObject`, but it makes sense that it wouldn't have a constructor taking another `JsObject`. Can you use `JsObject("someKey" -> _)`?